# Python session not persisting cookies in google cloud compute enginee

Tags: docker, google-cloud-platform, python-requests

I used session across multiple python scripts to persist the login details.

It works fine in the local machine. After I login using the session, I can then request information in other web pages.

But after I set it up using docker to google cloud compute enginee, the scripts are not working.

After inspecting the issue, I found that the the cookies are not kept.

Anyone knows about this issue?

Comment: You have a bug in your code, but you do not show any code. Read this link and try to improve your question: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: I have made it work using Alpine instead of ubuntu in docker